# How to migrate existing Xamarin.iOS project into Xamarin.Forms code?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to move my development completely into Xamarin.Forms. Currently, everything was developed using Xamarin.iOS and now i want to move to Forms due to some requirements. How to use my existing Xamarin.iOS code on Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: I havent used it yet but they say mvvmcross might make your life easier. just take a look at it if you havent used it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way for this. You need to redo your application in Forms/Xaml, which takes time. You can use some iOS specific code in Xamarin.Forms renderers specifically for iOS specific styling.

There is no easy way for this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

**No Automation available**. You need to do it manually. and its not going to be simple. You will have to rewrite almost all code involved with UI. you can reuse code written for business logic but for all other, you need to rewrite with Forms/Xamml.